# Как сделать чтобы список фильтров на мобильный устройствах можно было прокручивать но чтобы на остальной странице не возникал горизонтальный скролл?

Tags: html, css, прокрутка

как сделать чтобы скролл работал только для меню фильтров,а не для всей страницы? может дело в ширине?

```css
 .main__nav
    {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: 115px;
        margin-top:24px;
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        gap:8px;
        justify-content: start;
        /*max-width: 633px;*/
        height: 44px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        min-width: 1200px;
    }
    .border{
        display: flex;
        /*padding:6px 8px ;*/
        align-items: stretch;
        border:1px solid #C1C5CD;
        border-radius: 24px;
        gap:4px;
        height: 20px;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family:Montserrat,sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        align-self: stretch;

    }
    .main__self
    {
        border: 1px solid #16C8BB;
    }
```

```html
 <ul class="main__nav">
    <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border" href='#'>Все</a></li>
        <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Самооценка и самопринятие</span></a></li>
    <li class="main__nav_item"><a class=" border main__self" href='#'><span>&#129412;Self</span></a></li>
    <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long main__item" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Чувства и эмоции</span></a></li>
    <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border main__item" href='#'><span>Тревога</span></a></li>
    <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border main__item" href='#'><span>Упражнения</span></a></li>
    <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long main__item" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Психология питания</span></a></li>
    <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border main__item" href='#'><span>Насилие</span></a></li>
    <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long main__item" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Личное здоровье</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); в частности, обратите внимание, что весь текст вопроса не надо помещать в заголовок. заголовок должен кратко но ёмко описывать суть вопроса.

Comment: для начала стоит познакомиться с виртуальными пикселями и DPR из которого они вытекают. первое что нагуглилось на великом и могучем, вот это: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/128978/ исходя из чего ваше `min-width: 1200px` будет раза эдак в 3 шире чем экран большинства мобил.

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте списку растягиваться на всю доступную ширину, убрав `min-width: 1200px`, и принудительно установите полосу прокрутки только по горизонтали с помощью `overflow: scroll hidden`:

```css
.main__nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  overflow: scroll hidden;
}

.border {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #C1C5CD;
  border-radius: 24px;
  font: 600 14px/1em Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.main__self { border: 1px solid #16C8BB; }
```

```html
<ul class="main__nav">
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border" href='#'>Все</a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Самооценка и самопринятие</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class=" border main__self" href='#'><span>&#129412;Self</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long main__item" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Чувства и эмоции</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border main__item" href='#'><span>Тревога</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border main__item" href='#'><span>Упражнения</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long main__item" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Психология питания</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border main__item" href='#'><span>Насилие</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long main__item" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Личное здоровье</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Насколько я понял, все эти отступы в вашем коде - это попытка спрятать стрелки полосы прокрутки. Это проще сделать используя собственные стили:

```css
.main__nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  overflow: scroll hidden;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.border {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #C1C5CD;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
  font: 600 14px/1em Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.main__self { border: 1px solid #16C8BB; }

/* Firefox */
.main__nav { scrollbar-width: thin; scrollbar-color: #ddd4 #ddd2; }
.main__nav:hover { scrollbar-color: #ddd #ddd4; }
/* Chrome, Edge, Safari */
.main__nav::-webkit-scrollbar { height: 6px; width: 6px; }
.main__nav::-webkit-scrollbar-track { background-color: #ddd2; border-radius: 100vmax; }
.main__nav:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-track { background-color: #ddd4; }
.main__nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: #ddd4; border-radius: 100vmax; }
.main__nav:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: #ddd; }
```

```html
<ul class="main__nav">
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border" href='#'>Все</a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Самооценка и самопринятие</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class=" border main__self" href='#'><span>&#129412;Self</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long main__item" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Чувства и эмоции</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border main__item" href='#'><span>Тревога</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border main__item" href='#'><span>Упражнения</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long main__item" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Психология питания</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border main__item" href='#'><span>Насилие</span></a></li>
  <li class="main__nav_item"><a class="border border_long main__item" href='#'><span class="main__nav_text">Личное здоровье</span></a></li>
</ul>
```